# Strings replacement in data.frame. Multiple occurrences

Tags: r, string, dataframe

For the following example data.fame

```
df <- data.frame(n=as.integer(seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1)),
                 s1=as.character(rep(x = "abc|efg|hij|klm", times = 5)), 
                 s2=as.character(rep(x = "ABC - EFG - HIJ - KLM", times = 5)), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

df

  n              s1                    s2
1 1 abc|efg|hij|klm ABC - EFG - HIJ - KLM
2 2 abc|efg|hij|klm ABC - EFG - HIJ - KLM
3 3 abc|efg|hij|klm ABC - EFG - HIJ - KLM
4 4 abc|efg|hij|klm ABC - EFG - HIJ - KLM
5 5 abc|efg|hij|klm ABC - EFG - HIJ - KLM
```

i need to replace the "|" character in the s1 column with a single character ";" and for the column s2 replace the string " - " with " |" in order to obtian the following data.frame

```
  n              s1                 s2
1 1 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
2 2 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
3 3 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
4 4 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
5 5 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gsub` on the columns 's1' and 's2', match the patterns `|`, `-` and replace it with `;` and `|`.

```
df$s1 <- gsub('[|]', ';', df$s1)
df$s2 <-  gsub('-\\s+', '|', df$s2)
df
#  n              s1                 s2
#1 1 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#2 2 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#3 3 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#4 4 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#5 5 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
```

---

Another option if we have multiple patterns to replace is `mgsub` from `library(qdap)`.  We loop through the 2nd and 3rd columns using `lapply`, do `mgsub` on individual columns by specifying the `pattern` and `replacement` as a `vector`.

```
library(qdap)
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], mgsub, pattern=c('[|]', '-\\s+'), 
                   replacement=c(';', '|'), fixed=FALSE)
df
#  n              s1                 s2
#1 1 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#2 2 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#3 3 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#4 4 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
#5 5 abc;efg;hij;klm ABC |EFG |HIJ |KLM
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear answer (first option). I'm solved my impasse. Tiziano